# NetBeans. Connect to hosting database

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans

I've got database on shared hosting.
Is it possible connect to that database from NetBeans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with the condition: **Your database is allowed to be accessed from outside. This, usually by setting host to `%` on database configuration**

To see if it does allowed, you need to see the database admin panel and or ask your hosting provider. Because, different hosting offer different control panel and usually map database setting to different configuration page.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah definitely you need the shared hosting account to allow public access to the database, grab the credentials used to log in from the host and go to netbeans

1. window > services >
2. then in the services panel right click Database
3. then click new connection
4. fil lin the form with the credentials and your all set

This is hoping you are using netbeans 6.9.1